# How to get random samples from a table? I don't want repeated records between samples

Tags: sql-server

I have this problem, I want to get some random extracts from a table and I dont want repeated records between those extracts, in order that when I join all the different samples together, they look as the main table.

I am working with sql server 2012

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

TABLESAMPLE can't provide the mutually exclusive nature between samples that you need even with its REPEATABLE seed.  So I would consider rolling your own, using something like NTILE.  eg assuming your table has a primary key and you want 10 samples, create a table which contains the sample Id and the primary key of the table.  Use it as a 'master' to create your samples from, then you're guaranteed they will not overlap.  Here's a simple example:

```
-- Create your sample master table; I'm using a temp table here
-- but you could use a permanent one
SELECT NTILE(10) OVER( ORDER BY NEWID() ) sampleId, yourPrimaryKey
INTO #tmp
FROM dbo.yourTable

-- Create the sample, eg sample 3 of 10
SELECT m.*
FROM dbo.yourTable m
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM #tmp t
    WHERE t.sampleId = 3
      AND m.yourPrimaryKey = t.yourPrimaryKey
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Both answers allowed me to solve my problem, what I did was to order my query using the function  newid() in order to get a random sample, after that I created a new index and I saved  the result on a new table.
The mutually exclusive samples were obtained by selecting ranges whit the variable new index.

```
select
IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS ID_Num,
-----
-----
into JIC_MODEXP2
from
    -----
where 
    -----
order by newid()
```

MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE SAMPLES

```
SELECT
----
----
FROM JIC_MODEXP2
where ID_num between 100000 and 200000
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the TABLESAMPLE syntax for your extracts.  But random by nature may duplicate some results.  I imagine that you are storing these in a table somewhere?  You could use TABLESAMPLE for the extract and then MERGE to ensure you didn't get duplicates.

Or you could modify the query itself

```
SELECT * FROM tabletest TABLESAMPLE (10 PERCENT) WHERE NOT(PrimaryKey IN (SELECT PrimaryKey FROM extracttable))
```

[TABLESAMPLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Be aware TABLESAMPLE ignores a page or uses all of that page. For smaller tables, for any one execution, this may a) heavily skew results b) not return any results at all.